# Difference between Mac OSX nslookup and resolveip

Tags: nslookup

I assumed nslookup would either error when looking up non internet names or would give the correct answer but I'm confused by the following behaviour.  Have I misunderstood how to use it or its output/limitations?

```
$ resolveip raspberrypi.local
IP address of raspberrypi.local is 192.168.0.41
$ nslookup raspberrypi.local
Server:     194.168.4.100
Address:    194.168.4.100#53

** server can't find raspberrypi.local: NXDOMAIN
```

The answer of `192.168.0.41` from resolveip is correct but the nslookup answer is not correct.  Also I'm wondering what the `#53` part of the address is referring to.  Surely it's not port number.  The man page for nslookup doesn't seem to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of resolveip vs nslookup was already discussed a little [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134576/difference-between-nslookup-host-and-resolveip) already but it seems *resolveip* will check hosts and then move on to DNS checks while *nslookup* will go straight to DNS. So I would assume that it knows the pi from either the hosts file or from the local network via some other means (arp?), it seems that the pi is not registered with your DNS server.

Also the #53 refers to the port that responded from the server. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65431/nslookup-how-to-interpret-output) discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I assumed `nslookup` was doing something like that but then was confused by why it even returned anything (and why it was incorrect).  Regarding `resolveip`, yes I would have thought it's using arp or something similar as `arp raspberrypi.local` returns the correct ip address.  The raspberry pi is using mDNS (which I don't understand yet) to ? "broadcast" it's IP? / ?request a particular IP from the DHCP server? .

Comment: "When an mDNS client needs to resolve a host name, it sends an IP multicast query message that asks the host having that name to identify itself. That target machine then multicasts a message that includes its IP address." -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS